# How to asynchronously flush a memory mapped file?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, memory-mapped-files

I am using memory mapped files to have read-/write-access to a large number of image files (~10000 x 16 MB) under Windows 7 64bit. My goals are:

1. Having as much data cached as possible.
2. Being able to allocate new images and write to those as fast as possible.

Therefore I am using memory mapped files to access the files. Caching works well, but the OS is not flushing dirty pages until I am nearly out of physical memory. Because of that allocating and writing to new files is quite slow once the physical memory is filled.

One solution would be to regularly use `FlushViewOfFile()`, but this function does not return until the data has been writen to disk.

Is there a way to asynchroniously flush a file mapping? The only solution I found is to `Unmap()` and `MapViewOfFile()` again, but using this approach I can not be sure to get the same data pointer again. Can someone suggest a better approach?

Edit:
Reading the `WINAPI` documentation a little longer, it seems that I found a suitable solution to my problem:

Calling `VirtualUnlock()` on a memory range that is not locked results in a flushing of dirty pages.

Answer (score 2):

I heard that FlushViewOfFile() function does NOT wait until it physically write to file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366563(v=vs.85).aspx

> The FlushViewOfFile function **does not flush the file metadata, and it does not wait to return until the changes are flushed** from the underlying hardware disk cache and physically written to disk.

After call "FlushFileBuffers( ... )" then your data will be physically written to disk.

Comment: I have just performed micro-benchmarks on Windows 10, and the call `FlushViewOfFile()` is blocking (although it might not be intended that way). Do you have any insight on replicating the `MS_ASYNC` behavior of Linux?